# Changing image in different view

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, viewcontroller

I am attempting to change the character image in the game that I am creating but I am having some issues. I have a view controller where I will have all of the characters as their own buttons, and by selecting a button it should change the character image in the GameViewController

**change.h**

```
- (IBAction)charOne:(id)sender;
```

**change.m**

```
- (IBAction)charOne:(id)sender 
{

    GameViewController *changeView = [GameViewController game];
    UIImageView *Romo = [GameView changeView];

    [ChangeView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testOne.png"]];

    NSLog(@"Test");

}
```

**GameViewController.m**

```
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *changeView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *changeView;
```

This code isn't working for me, I do not receive an error message but nothing is changed after the image is selected.

On the GameViewController the UIImage name that I am attempting to change the image for is named Romo.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: here changeView is new instance of object created as you need the instance already being used of GameViewController to change image

Comment: Bin `IBOutlet UIImageView *changeView;` there is absolutely no reason to have this here because you have the `@property` which will generate the ivar for you. I also assume that `ChangeView` the uppercase `C` is a typo? And also change the file names to have uppercase `C` so will be **Change.h** and if the class name is starts with lowercase change that to, classes start with uppercase (With matching file name) and variables start with lowercase. What is Change and GameViewController? Please share all interface code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

```
[Romo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testOne.png"]];
```

instead of :

```
[ChangeView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testOne.png"]];
```

You're calling the setImage method on a class rather than an instance of a class. Since `Romo` is the instance of UIImageView you want to affect (which is a reference pointer to the UIImageView on your game view controller), that should be the instance you affect.

Also, bad practice to name instances starting with a capital letter -- they turn out looking like classes.